# Ubuntu Server: Fail to restart networking.service: Unit network.service not found

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu

I add some a line `dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8` in my `/etc/network/interfaces`.
I want to reload this config without reboot.

However, when I tried:
`sudo service networking restart`
I got a `Unit networking.service not found` error

`sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`
I got `/etc/init.d/networking: command not found`

How can I fix this?
I use Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Things have changed over time. Dependent on your installation, you want to check the service names with

```
systemctl list-unit-files | grep -i network
```

And, *most likely* in your case, it's

```
systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Comment: `Unit NetworkManager.service not found` on Ubuntu 18.04 server.

Comment: @Kaz What's your output of `systemctl list-unit-files | grep -i network`?

Comment: Like this: https://pastebin.com/raw/1pmmHw9G

Comment: @Kaz Yeah, thanks. Then your networking is managed without *NetworkManager* and solely by *systemd-networkd*. In your case it's `systemctl restart systemd-networkd` then.

Comment: An Ubuntu update on 20.10 changed it for me today apparently from `network-manager` to `NetworkManager`

Comment: `Failed to restart NetworkManager.service: Unit NetworkManager.service not found` on Ubuntu server 20.04

Comment: In Ubuntu server 20.04 LTS only have: `networkd-dispatcher.service`, `systemd-network-generator.service`, `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service`, `systemd-networkd.service`, `systemd-networkd.socket`, `network-online.target`, `network-pre.target` and `network.target`, but last 2 are disabled.

Answer (score 2):

Since version  15.04, Ubuntu comes with  systemd as default instead of initd. [systemd-networkd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/systemd.network.5.html) exactly

Use `systemctl restart networking`

Comment: Results in `Unit networking.service not found` on Ubuntu 18.04 server.